# Will I require MS Excel installed on the server if I am generating Excel file using NetOffice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, npoi, netoffice

I am trying out both **NetOffice** and **NPOI** for to use in an ASP.NET project.

I am making an ASP.NET web site where on click of a button, I want to **generate** an Excel file in a **password protected** state and send it to the client to download it.

But I want to know whether, **will I require MS Excel installed on the server?** 
OR Is there a way where I can make this work on a server where MS Excel is **NOT** installed?

Also what are other pre-requisites for both these APIS?

I basically have to identify which of these APIs will work for me in a server without Microsoft Excel installed in it.

Comment: No need to installed , I think !

Comment: Emphasizing isn't required in this case imo. And isn't what oftenly used on SO too.

Answer (score 3):

Please check documentation: http://netoffice.codeplex.com/documentation at question

**What do I have to do to deliver my application with NetOffice?**
Nothing except copying the needed assemblies to the target system. You don't need a registration or something like that with the exception of COMAddIns. Managed COMAddins generally have to be registered via the .Net Utility RegAsm.exe or the Windows Installer do that or you.